# Face maps not exporting with the model as .glTF 2.0

Tags: faces, vertex-groups, gltf

I'm working on a low poly model that needs to be exported as glTF.

It needs to use face maps to hide parts of the geometry where clothing will be used instead.

I've tried both embedded and separate .glTF options, as well as the only .glb option.

None of them export the face maps, and when I import them back into a new blender scene, all the verts have been ripped so there are about 4x as many as the model that was just exported, which is highly undesirable for the project.

Blender version is 3.2.0 (the exact one from the .org homepage).

glTF importer/exporter is the one that comes packaged with blender, 3.2.40.

A colleague told me she was able to export the model with the face maps saved using blender version 2.93, and glTF import/export version 1.5.5. (I don't remember 2.93 having face maps as a feature though)

The model she exported does indeed show the face maps in the viewer we are using to check out the models (https://viewer.relm.us/), but when I import it into blender, it does not contain any face maps, and the verts are still all ripped, quadrupling the poly count.

She suggested I use this version of the glTF import/export: https://github.com/canadaduane/glTF-Blender-IO (this version appears to be 1.8.6 though, so not even the same as the one she is using)

And after trying it, the models still did not export with face maps or show any face maps in the viewer, so I am completely stumped on how to solve this.

(I also added a single vertex group for testing, which also doesn't import with the model when I bring it into a new blender scene.)

Comment: Face Maps are a Blender-specific concept, I'm not sure what (if anything) Blender's glTF exporter will do with them. Certainly a glTF file imported back into Blender will never contain Face Maps. Assigning different materials to different groups of vertices might do better. Differences in vertex count usually have to do with vertex attributes like normals and UVs — if you don't need them and can disable them from export, that may help. Otherwise there are optimizing tools like gltfpack or gltf-transform that can sometimes reduce vertex count.

Comment: Thank you Don. I have very little experience with this and any information is helpful to know. I'll see what I can do with what you've given me.